# Add legend when using a subset

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, legend

I need to plot a variable and a subset of this variable into one graph and I struggle with the placement of the legend. See the following MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = cars, aes(x = speed)) +
  geom_line(stat = "density", colour = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_area(stat = "density", fill = "red", alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(data = subset(cars, dist > 50), stat = "density", colour = "blue", size = 1) +
  geom_area(data = subset(cars, dist > 50), stat = "density", fill = "blue", alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

Please note that it is not an option to incluce `fill = dist > 50` in the aesthetics for this would split the data into two distinct parts. But the first `geom_line` and `geom_area` must not only include those values with `dist <= 0`, but all values from the data.

Therefore I specify the colors manually in the `geom`'s. But how can I now add a legend? I would prefer to only include the two `geom_line`'s.

I tried with `scale_color_manual` but did not bring it to work (if this is the way to go, anyway?).

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: I changed the code in order to show a working minimal example.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to prepare the data outside ggplot, see example:

```
# data prep
plotDat <- rbind(
  data.frame(Group = "Full Data", cars),
  data.frame(Group = "Subset Data", cars[cars$speed < 15, ]))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plotDat, aes(x = speed, col = Group, fill = Group)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: I just realized that this is not an answer for my question since the plot from your suggestion stacks the density plots. Thus, it's a totally different graph.

I added `position = "dodge"` to `geom_area` to get the graph I was looking for. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: @der_grund correct, used the wrong plot function, see edit.